# jQuery html() converts angular attributes to lowercase

Tags: jquery, html, angular, angular5

e.g-> 
Expected output of below code:

```
$('<div><label [routerLink]="[\'/test\']">Footer text 1</label></div>').html()
```

Expected Output:

```
<label [routerLink]="['/test']">Footer text 1</label>
```

But actual output is different:

```
 <label [routerlink]="['/test']">Footer text 1</label>
```

How to solve this?

Comment: _How to solve this?_ Simple. Don't use jQuery to create angular code

Answer (score 0):

You should not rely on JQuery to read Angular DOM elements. The directives used on elements are not guaranteed to even appear in DOM. You use them in Angular, right now they do appear in the DOM, but that's an internal implementation detail of Angular. At some point in time, that might change. They might be called differently in DOM, they might not appear at all. That they appear is not a supported feature.

So whatever you are trying to do, you probably need to find another way.

Comment: Reading angular attributes with jquery is not a problem (although writing is). Problem occurs while trying to read the raw html containing angular attributes though jQuery and then writing it back.

Comment: Accessing information from DOM elements in a way that's not defined in any binding API maybe isn't a problem per se, but it will cause problems